# Is there a way to directly "decorate" a block of Python code?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a bunch of code:

```
statement1(args)
statement2(args)
statement3(args)
statement4(args)
statement5(args)
```

I want to divide the statements into blocks and write to a log after each block.  The logging is a bit complex: I want to log things like the running time of each block and the state of a particular data structure after the block executes.  So I created a decorator called `log_block` which handles all of these details.  Now my code looks like this:

```
@log_block()
def block1():
    statement1(args)
    statement2(args)

@log_block()
def block2()
    statement3(args)

@log_block()
def block3():
    statement4(args)
    statement5(args)

block1()
block2()
block3()
```

This works just fine, but it's a little clunky.  It's annoying that I have to separately call the three block functions, and if I want to share a variable between the blocks then I either have to give the block functions arguments and return statements or use global variables, neither of which is particularly palatable.  What I really want is syntax which looks like this:

```
@log_block()
    statement1(args)
    statement2(args)

@log_block()
    statement3(args)

@log_block()
    statement4(args)
    statement5(args)
```

so that I am decorating the statements directly rather than enclosing them in auxiliary block functions.  Is there any way to achieve something like this?

Comment: That won't work with decorators. Have you looked into *"context managers"*? `with log_block(): ...`

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Why just not call the function log_block()? What I understand, you do not intend to modify the behavior, by providing a replacement of the statements following it. So, you are probably overthinking. Moreover, context manager might be useful if you want to maintain a scope under which the statements needs to be executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) are exactly what you are looking for. You use them with the `with` statement, and they define code to be run on entering and exiting the with block.

Comment: I had never built a context manager before, it but it turned out to be quite easy and indeed it was exactly what I needed.  Thanks!